# Spring Mvc Session Creation only after login

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

In my project i am using session  and  my deafult url is "index".  problem is when i run project session is created. But i want to create session only after the user is logged in to the project.
  This is my code

```
<form-login  login-page="/index"    default-target-url="/" 
         authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                 username-parameter="username"
                 password-parameter="password" />
     <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />            
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/Access_Denied" /> 

     <session-management invalid-session-url="/login?timeout"/>
```

And in web.xml i give timeout like

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

i used ifrequired too Then to spring is creating session after my default url is hit.
What should i do?
what changed i need to do?
need valuable guidance

Answer (score 0):

By default the jsp page sets the session flag to true. Set this in your index page jsp and the session won't get created.

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not working @AtherSajjad please tell me why it is not working

Comment: I checked it doesn't create session. Keep it in the index.jsp and restart the server and clear the browser cache and then check